# Do gesture recognizers override the scrollview's ability to scroll?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, scrollview, uigesturerecognizer

In my app, a top view has pan gesture recognizers to move the view to the left and to the right to reveal two other views underneath it. I'm trying to put a scrollview into the top view, but i can't seem to get it to scroll. I'm using storyboards for the scrollview but the gesture recognizer is implemented programmatically. I have the scroller insets set to exceed the size.

I'm thinking that maybe the gesture recognizers take priority over the scrollview's ability to scroll, but I can't find any way to check.. Unless I'm looking over something stupid, could someone please help with this?

Answer (score 3):

UIScrollView implements a private UISwipeGestureRecognizer that does hold priority over any other gesture.  But, it's one many people have overridden (it's fairly easy, just a for-in loop or two) to hook into it's events or provide their own subclass, which is the only way to get other gestures to recognize simultaneously.  Actually, that's the name of the delegate method you need to implement, `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`